# Why all elements in my array are the same?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a function to create array dynamically, however the elements in array created are all the same. All elements are overwritten by the last one.

Is this an VBA issue or any where I am doing wrong? Can anybody help on this? thank you in advance.

```
For count = 1 To 2
    Set sheet = deviceBook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    Set find = sheet.range("A1", GetColName(sheet.UsedRange.Columns.count, sheet) & "1")
    With find   
    carrierClo = GetCellColumn(carrierTitle, sheet, find)   
    modelNoCol = GetCellColumn(modelNoTitle, sheet, find)
    End With
    For row = 2 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
        If sheet.range(carrierClo & row).value <> ""
        And sheet.range(modelNoCol & row).value <> "" Then
            With plm
                .carrierName = sheet.range(carrierClo & row).value
                .modelNo = sheet.range(modelNoCol & row).value
                Set plms(UBound(plms)) = plm
                ReDim Preserve plms(UBound(plms) + 1)
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: If `plm` is an object you need to instantiate a new one each cycle. Try putting `Set plm = New ***` right before `With plm` if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, after I set plm to new object, it works correctly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As answered in comments of the OP's question:

> If plm is an object you need to instantiate a new one each cycle. Try putting Set plm = New *** right before With plm if that's the case. -- xificurC